# Type 'LucideIcon' is not assignable to type 'string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, tailwind-css

How do I use  an  Icon from LucideIcon to pass into the react component. I have attached the following code. Trying to import the icon from LucideIcons dynamically by mapping into the page.tsx

My code:
kayakdescription.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link"

const KayakDesc = ({
  image,
  title,
  subinfo,
}: {
  image: string
  title: string
  subinfo: string
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex border rounded-xl w-72 h-40 mx-2 dark:border-gray-400">
      <div className="flex p-4">
        {image}
        <div className="flex-col ml-4">
          <div className=" font-bold text-lg ">{title}</div>
          <div className="text-xs mt-4 ">{subinfo}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default KayakDesc
```

page.tsx

```
  <div className="flex flex-row">
          {Kayaktitleinfo.map((info) => (
            <KayakDesc
              key={info.title}
              title={info.title}
              subinfo={info.subinfo}
              image={info.image}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```

kayaktitleinfo.ts

```
import { BedDouble } from "lucide-react"

export const Kayaktitleinfo = [
  {
    title: "Search for the best hotel deals",
    subinfo: "Compare deals from 3M+ hotels and accommodations in one place.",
    image: BedDouble,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed code:

kayakdescription.tsx

```js
import Link from "next/link"
import { LucideIcon } from "lucide-react" // <--- import type from library

const KayakDesc = ({
  Icon, // <--- new prop name
  title,
  subinfo,
}: {
  Icon: LucideIcon // <--- add typing
  title: string
  subinfo: string
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex border rounded-xl w-72 h-40 mx-2 dark:border-gray-400">
      <div className="flex p-4">
        <Icon /> {/* <--- use like component  */}
        <div className="flex-col ml-4">
          <div className=" font-bold text-lg ">{title}</div>
          <div className="text-xs mt-4 ">{subinfo}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default KayakDesc
```

page.tsx

```js
  <div className="flex flex-row">
          {Kayaktitleinfo.map((info) => (
            <KayakDesc
              key={info.title}
              title={info.title}
              subinfo={info.subinfo}
              Icon={info.image} // <--- use new name for prop `Icon`
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```